# How can I exchange information between my components?

Tags: vuejs3

I am still new to Vuejs and confused by the many different possibilities in exchanging data between different components. So far I haven't found a working solution for my case.

### My setup:

I am building an application of which four components are relevant here: AppComponent, MenuComponent, ContentDisplayComponent, NavigationComponent. In the MenuComponent there is a dropdown that selects a value. This value is displayed on ContentDisplayComponent and it affects the doings of NavigationComponent.

### Already working:

In **AppComponent**, the data I want to pass around is initiated:

```
data() {
  return {
    selected_entity_type : "test",
  }},
```

The value is actually coming from **MenuComponent** by passing it an event function:

```
v-on:entity_type_selected="something_happened"
```

Function looks like this:

```
function something_happened(selected_type) {
    if (is_empty(selected_type)) {
        console.warn("selected type was empty");
    }
    this.selected_entity_type = selected_type;
}
```

In **MenuComponent** the dropdown reacts to changes:

```
<select v-model="selected_entity_type" v-on:change="entity_type_selected">
```

Function looks like this:

```
function entity_type_selected() {
    this.$emit('entity_type_selected', this.selected_entity_type)
}
```

It is given to **ContentDisplayComponent**

```
v-bind:selected_entity_type = "selected_entity_type"
```

where it is received as a prop and used

```
props: {
  selected_entity_type : ""
},
```

So in my understanding the variable is actually under the scope of **AppComponent**, but its value is passed into **ContentDisplayComponent** and its content is changed by the event **MenuComponent** emits which is caught by v-on:entity_type_selected="something_happened".

I assume that because the function "something_happened" is given to **MenuComponent** from **AppComponent**, the "this" it contains refers to **AppComponent** and thus can handle the variable.

### What I want to add, but don't know how:

**NavigationComponent** can change the data displayed in **ContentDisplayComponent**. When this happens, I would like to also change the state of the dropdown in **MenuComponent** and the value of the *selected_entity_type prop* in **ContentDisplayComponent**. **ContentDisplayComponent's** data is manipulated via and maintained in a Composable. **NavigationComponent** uses that Composable to change the contents. But the *selected_entity_type prop* is not in there, since it's in **AppComponent** and I don't know how to reach it.

### What would be the best way to achieve this?

I would like to understand the principle idea.

Looking through these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775876/vue-3-pass-reactive-object-to-component-with-two-way-binding) [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260233/difference-between-v-model-and-v-bind-on-vue-js) I don't want to violate any principles with things that might work. I would like to do it right.

I am trying to emit information from **ContentDisplayComponent**, but it cannot change the variable and cannot use the functions **MenuComponent** and **AppComponent** use for their sharing.

Another possibility would be to move *selected_entity_type prop* into my data Composable so it is under direct control. But then **ContentDisplayComponent** has to exchange that information with **MenuComponent** and I don't know if that's possible.

Please help me understand what is the Vue3 idea of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works for me - although I don't know if that's the most-native Vuejs style.

Looking at [the documentation about state management](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api), I wondered whether it would be wrong to use my existing Composable to manage the state by itself. Looking around on the internet, I found no article saying "absolutely no!". So that's what I did.

My Composable now defines this state variable once:

```
const selected_entity_type = ref("no type selected");
```

and exports getters and setters for it:

```
function set_selected_entity_type(new_type: string) {
  selected_entity_type.value = new_type;
}

function get_selected_entity_type(): string {
  return selected_entity_type.value;
}
```

These getters and setters can be used by all Components now via importing the Composable.

For the dropdown I am using a computed value as my v-model (like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093887/vue-two-way-binding-for-select-element-using-v-bind-and-props))

```
computed: {
  selected_entity_type: {
    get() { return this.get_selected_entity_type() },
    set(value) { 
      this.reset_state(); 
      this.set_selected_entity_type(value);
    }
  }
}
```

AppComponent now has nothing to do with all of this anymore - no more events, no more props ...

Please let me know if you see any problems with this approach and recommend improvements.